# Passing Multiple State Variables through Outlet Context

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to utilize react-router's [useOutletContext](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#useoutletcontext) to pass a few state variables from my top down component (Page) to children generated in the outlet

I'm getting a bit stuck on how to add *multiple* state variables into context.

**Working Code for a Single State Variable**

*Parent Component*

```
<Outlet context={[currentValue1, setCurrentValue1]} />
```

*Child Component*

```
const [currentValue1, setCurrentValue1] = useOutletContext();

return (<h1>{currentValue1}</h1>)
```

How would I pass through `[currentValueN, setCurrentValueN]` in addition to `currentValue1`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass more than two elements in an array.

```
<Outlet
  context={[
    currentValue1, setCurrentValue1,
    currentValue2, setCurrentValue2,
    ...
    currentValueN, setCurrentValueN
  ]}
/>
```

You could also use an object. This avoids the need to skip destructuring via the array when you want the Nth element, i.e. `const [,,,,,,currentValueN] = useOutletContext();`

```
<Outlet
  context={{
    currentValue1, setCurrentValue1,
    currentValue2, setCurrentValue2,
    ...
    currentValueN, setCurrentValueN
  }}
/>
```

...

```
const { currentValueN } = useOutletContext();
```

It's really up to you how you want to pass all the data/properties.

Comment: Appreciate it. Didn't realize that useOutletContext basically just held context variables like a normal array or data object. I had thought there was some more property magic going on. Thanks!

Comment: @AhmedHaque  Nope, it's just a regular React context, i.e. a bucket that can hold any normal Javascript value.